# Why async AWS Java SDK is using a thread pool?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, nonblocking

It's 2016 already and Java AWS SDK doesn't have truly non blocking API, which avoids thread pools (I mean thread per api request scheme)! But why? What if I want to create a massive messaging app or finally Pokemon Go killer based on DynamoDB, I will need to scale to hundreds of rest api VM's instead of just tens in case of non-blocking IO for the same load (millions requests per second). Also what is the benefit for me to use something very powerful like Akka or Vert.x if essential part of storage apis use thread per request?

Comment: Can't answer your question, but whenever there's a talk of getting async support for something, this article should be referenced: http://techblog.bozho.net/why-non-blocking/

Comment: The thread pool is to do the actual work. How do you think an asynchronous, non-blocking gets its work done?

Comment: @kaqqao the article is good, and for small loads it's fully true. However in the high load chamber it's a bit different. Consider you have a rest api which processes requests 5 ms at average. Consider also you use a blocking approach and 4.9 ms your thread simply waits for outer systems to reply, however resources for a thread still be used. Which resources? Memory (java by default have 256kb for a stack for each thread) and a processor (just try to start 10k sleeping threads in Java and see how your processor will be loaded). Non blocking approach allows saving those resources.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No. Thread pool is not necessary. Consider for example Vert.x mongodb api (http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/), it's non blocking and requests to db doesn't use thread pools. The problem is implementation itself, there is no fundamental problems to do it.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you were complaining about having to use thread pools to shield blocking APIs from the non-blocking parts.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, thx, I edited the actual post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS finally released v2.0 java SDK with "truly asynchronous" method calls. You can refer to their docs for more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/whats-new.html

Keep in mind, however, that not all features of SDK v1.x were implemented in v2.0 for now, the list of "Features not yet in the AWS SDK for Java 2.0" could be found here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html